# How To Run a Node JS file in a Live Browser

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, node-modules

I am attempting to create an html page that contains an input field, and a button. Once the user clicks the button, I want the page to run a Node JS File.

Currently, the html script simply displays the input, but I would link the input to be fed into a function in the Node JS File, and the output be displayed/stored.

From my understanding, this is only possible in a live browser. I have attempted to use npm live-server as well as the VScode live-server extension.

However whenever I start the server I get this error in the console.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/RecipeScrapper/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
In the** Network tab** the summary says:
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/RecipeScrapper/index.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**This is my File Structure**

```
Desktop
| -- node_modules(folder)
| -- index.html
| -- index.js
| -- package.json
| -- package-lock
```

**Relevant part of html file:**

```
<head>
    <Title>Recipe</Title>
    <script type="module" src="/RecipeScrapper/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ... 
    <button onclick= "Display(document.getElementById('a').value)"> Display Link </button>
 </body>
```

**Relevant part of index.js**

```
Relevant part of index.js file
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
async function getItems(a) { 
    try {
      const response = await fetch (a); 
      const body = await response.text();
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      const $wrapper4 = $('[data-test-id= "ingredients-list"] [data-test-id="ingredient-item-shipped"]');
      let uitems = [];

      $wrapper4.each((i, div) => {
        uitems.push($(div).text());
    });
    for(let i=0; i<uitems.length; i++)
    {
     ...
    }
    //print
    console.log(uitems)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
getItems('https://www.hellofresh.com/recipes/peppercorn-steak-w06-5857fcd16121bb11c124f383');
```

Files Repo: https://github.com/Anthony-S4/RecipeScrapper

I am very new to web development and I may be misunderstanding the difference between nodeJs and JS files.
From what I've seen it should be possible to accomplish this task using a live-browser. If I am misunderstood, an explanation of the difference between NodeJS and JS files being utilized in the browser would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript is a programming language that was originally designed to be interpreted and executed in a webbrowser. NodeJS allows for the interpretation of javascript code to be executed outside of a webbrowser. Each platform (webbrowser and nodejs) provides their own ways to do things, much of which overlap, but some that does not. 

Next, you have two components to webdev--client (browser) and a server (webserver). When you go to a page URL, the browser makes a request to the server, which returns HTML, Javascript & CSS, which the browser then displays.

Comment: In modern development, it's common to use NodeJS as a webserver, running javascript code to respond to requests made from a web browser. So, in order to do what you want--you need two seperate two parts: your nodejs file which will run on node, and the index.html/index.js file which will run in the browser. Your index.js should not make use of any node features (it can, but there really isn't a need to not just use plain old vanilla javascript).

Comment: That's not how you do it. The technique is the same as trying to run a PHP function or Java function or C# function: you create a HTTP endpoint in node.js and then send the data from the browser using either form submit or XMLHttpRequest or fetch. You need to treat node just like any other server-side language like C++ or Ruby or Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I've seen it should be possible to accomplish this task using a live-browser.

It isn't. JavaScript running in web browsers [don't have access to data on other websites](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) unless that website [gives explicit permission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

> If I am misunderstood, an explanation of the difference between NodeJS and JS files being utilized in the browser would be appreciated.

The key differences that are relevant here are that:

- Node.js can resolve module names by searching the file system, while browsers work on URLs
- Node.js and browsers have different APIs available to them (e.g. Node.js can make any HTTP request to any URL and read the response).

> any pointers as to how I can create an program/website to accomplish this task would also be appreciated

Write a web server using Node.js. [Express](https://expressjs.com/) is a popular library to do that. Call the code you have that depends on Node.js from an Express.js endpoint. Have the browser make an HTTP request to that endpoint (e.g. by submitting a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms) or using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)).

Comment: Ah okay thank you very much for the informative answer. Do you have any specific resources you would recommend for me to learn more about using web servers? I am very new to the topic. Thank you